# Can we override explicit cast in Java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

Say I have two classes A and B

```
Class A {
      int num;
      String name;
}
Class B {
      int num;
      String name;
      String age;
}
```

And I have `A extends B`  now if I have :

```
A a;
B b;
a = b;
```

But if I do : `b = a;` which will be explicit cast like this `b = (B)a;` the cast will be taking care by the java compiler... what if if I wanted to override this default explicit casting.

Say I want `b = (B)a` to give me something like `b` with properties a(num) and a(name) and "22" as age of b . If possible how do I do that ? in C# (iOS SDK) it's possible and doesn't give ClassCastException

Comment: The easiest way would be a `toB()` method in class `A` where you take care of that casting.

Comment: i want that to be automatic i don't want to call a method i want just  to do b = (B)a;